# Not able to change the Service StartMode

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I am automating an application deployment.

After installing and starting the service via Choco, I am trying to change the Service StartMode to Auto, but I am getting 21 as the returnvalue and hence the mode is not changed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $appservice = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='<app_name>'"
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $appservice.ChangeStartMode("Auto")


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 21
PSComputerName   :
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='<app_name>'"


ExitCode  : 0
Name      : <app_name>
ProcessId : 3180
StartMode : Manual
State     : Running
Status    : OK
```

Kindly help.
TIA

Comment: `Get-Service -Name 'TheServiceName'  | Set-Service –StartupType Automatic` ought to to it..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Get-Service -Name 'TheServiceName' | Set-Service –StartupType Automatic
```